# MS Exchange 2013 Unified Messaging issue, or really an AD issue?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2013

Where to begin...
I'd like to first admit that I am not an seasoned Exchange tech.
Second here is the environment:
(2) 2008 R2 DCs and (1) 2012 R2 MS Exchange 2013 server - other Exchange servers were removed [I've seen remnants of these old servers, but UM has been working fine until yesterday]

Our Exchange 2013 server stopped picking up calls on the voice access number assigned to it, for Unified Messaging. When trying to restart the, it fails to start with the following message [Windows could not start the Microsoft Exchange Unified Messaging service on Local Computer. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZLKo.png)

The service will hang on "Starting", but never actually start.

I proceed to the Event Viewer and see ALL sorts of Exchange related messages, however all pertaining to AD. For example:

**Error 1007: MSExchange Mailbox Replication**

The Mailbox Replication service was unable to determine the set of active mailbox databases on a mailbox server.
Mailbox server: 
Error: MapiExceptionNetworkError: Unable to make admin interface connection to server. (hr=0x80040115, ec=-2147221227)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 65256
    Lid: 49064   dwParam: 0x1
    Lid: 12514   Win32Error: 0x6D9
    Lid: 62184
    Lid: 16280   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ComputerName: n/a
    Lid: 8600    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ProcessID: 5456
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 0419-01-18T16:54:09.2670000Z
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 2
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Status: 1753
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 883
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 0
    Lid: 62184
    Lid: 16280   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ComputerName: n/a
    Lid: 8600    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ProcessID: 5456
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 0419-01-18T16:54:09.2670000Z
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 2
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Status: 1753
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 900
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 0
    Lid: 62184
    Lid: 16280   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ComputerName: n/a
    Lid: 8600    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: ProcessID: 5456
    Lid: 12696   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generation Time: 0419-01-18T16:54:09.2670000Z
    Lid: 10648   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Generating component: 2
    Lid: 14744   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Status: 1753
    Lid: 9624    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Detection location: 501
    Lid: 13720   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: Flags: 0
    Lid: 11672   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: NumberOfParameters: 4
    Lid: 8856    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: prm[0]: Unicode  string: ncalrpc
    Lid: 8856    dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: prm[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZLKo.png): Unicode  string: 
    Lid: 12952   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: prm[2]: Long val: 2306091726
    Lid: 12952   dwParam: 0x0 Msg: EEInfo: prm[3]: Long val: 382312662
    Lid: 24060   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 23746
    Lid: 31938   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 19650
    Lid: 27842   StoreEc: 0x80040115
    Lid: 20866
    Lid: 29058   StoreEc: 0x80040115

**Error 10006: MSExchange Mid-Tier Storage**

Active Manager Client experienced an AD timeout trying to lookup object '' in 00:01:00.

**Error 1002: MSExchangeThrottling**

The Microsoft Exchange Throttling Service encountered an Active Directory error while building an RPC security descriptor. This failure may indicate that no Domain Controllers are available at this time. The service will be stopped. Failure details: System.TimeoutException: Timed out AD operation after 00:00:30

**Error 4027: MSExchange ADAccess**

Process msexchangerepl.exe (PID=5808). WCF request (Get Servers for  The LDAP server returned an unknown error.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.BindWithLogging()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.BindWithRetry(Int32 maxRetries)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.PooledLdapConnection.BindWithRetry(Int32 maxRetries)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.LdapConnectionPool.CreateOneTimeConnection(NetworkCredential networkCredential, ADServerInfo serverInfo, LocatorFlags connectionFlags)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.LdapTopologyProvider.GetDirectoryServer(String partitionFqdn, ADRole role)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.LdapTopologyProvider.InternalGetServersForRole(String partitionFqdn, IList 1 currentlyUsedServers, ADServerRole role, Int32 serversRequested, Boolean forestWideAffinityRequested)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.LdapTopologyProvider.GetConfigDCInfo(String partitionFqdn, Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.PopulateConfigNamingContexts(String partitionFqdn)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.TopologyProvider.GetConfigurationNamingContext(String partitionFqdn)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADDataSession.GetNamingContext(ADNamingContext adNamingContext)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.Data.TopologyDiscoverySession.FindDirectoryServers(String site, List`1 dsFqdns)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.LocalForestTopologyDiscovery.FindPrimaryDS()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.ADTopologyDiscovery.Discover()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.ADTopologyDiscovery.DoWork(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.Common.WorkItem`1.Execute(CancellationToken joinedToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.TopologyDiscoveryManager.EndGetTopology(IAsyncResult ar)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.TopologyService.InternalEndGetServersForRole(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.TopologyService.<>c__DisplayClassa.b__9()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.TopologyService.ExecuteServiceCall(Action action)

**Error 2142: MSExchangeADTopolgy**

Process Microsoft.Exchange.Directory.TopologyService.exe (PID=2664) Forest . Topology discovery failed, error details 
Active Directory server  is not available. Error message: Active directory response: The LDAP server returned an unknown error..

So at this point I run a **DCDIAG** on the PDC (let's call is DC1, where the only other DC will be called DC2):

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:

Trying to find home server...

Home Server = dc1

- Identified AD Forest. 
  Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: \dc1

```
  Starting test: Connectivity

     ......................... dc1 passed test Connectivity
```

Doing primary tests

Testing server: \dc1

```
  Starting test: Advertising

     Fatal Error:DsGetDcName (dc1) call failed, error 1355

     The Locator could not find the server.

     ......................... dc1 failed test Advertising

  Starting test: FrsEvent

     There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the

     SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause

     Group Policy problems. 
     ......................... dc1 passed test FrsEvent

  Starting test: DFSREvent

     ......................... dc1 passed test DFSREvent

  Starting test: SysVolCheck

     ......................... dc1 passed test SysVolCheck

  Starting test: KccEvent

     ......................... dc1 passed test KccEvent

  Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders

     ......................... dc1 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders

  Starting test: MachineAccount

     ......................... dc1 passed test MachineAccount

  Starting test: NCSecDesc

     ......................... dc1 passed test NCSecDesc

  Starting test: NetLogons

     ......................... dc1 passed test NetLogons

  Starting test: ObjectsReplicated

     ......................... dc1 passed test ObjectsReplicated

  Starting test: Replications

     [Replications Check,Replications Check] Inbound replication is

     disabled.

     To correct, run "repadmin /options dc1 -DISABLE_INBOUND_REPL"

     [Replications Check,dc1] Outbound replication is disabled.

     To correct, run "repadmin /options dc1 -DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL"

     ......................... dc1 failed test Replications

  Starting test: RidManager

     ......................... dc1 passed test RidManager

  Starting test: Services

        w32time Service is stopped on [dc1]

        NETLOGON Service is paused on [dc1]

     ......................... dc1 failed test Services

  Starting test: SystemLog

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:28:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:33:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC00038D6

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:34:23

        Event String:

        The DFS Namespace service could not initialize cross forest trust information on this domain controller, but it will periodically retry the operation. The return code is in the record data.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:38:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:42:48

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:43:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:48:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:53:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   08:58:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   09:03:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   09:08:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   09:13:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   09:18:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x0000041E

        Time Generated: 01/18/2019   09:23:59

        Event String:

        The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not obtain the name of a domain controller. This could be caused by a name resolution failure. Verify your Domain Name System (DNS) is configured and working correctly.

     ......................... dc1 failed test SystemLog

  Starting test: VerifyReferences

     ......................... dc1 passed test VerifyReferences
```

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test

     CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test

     CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : Schema

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on : Configuration

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running partition tests on :

```
  Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

     ......................... <domain> passed test CheckSDRefDom

  Starting test: CrossRefValidation

     ......................... <domain> passed test CrossRefValidation
```

Running enterprise tests on : .com

```
  Starting test: LocatorCheck

     Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355

     A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.

     Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355

     A Time Server could not be located.

     The server holding the PDC role is down.

     Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error

     1355

     A Good Time Server could not be located.

     Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355

     A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.

     ......................... <domain>.com failed test LocatorCheck

  Starting test: Intersite

     ......................... <domain>.com passed test Intersite
```

To top this all off, DC2 was acting up so I restarted it. It no longer boots into Windows, instead I get this BSOD:

**STOP: c00002cb Security Manager Accounts Manager initialization failed because of the following error: The system cannot find the file specified**.

What a cluster, right?

Forgot to add an important query, **netdom query fsmo**:

"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
The command failed to complete successfully."

Inlcuding the list of domain roles via NTDSUtil:

**ntdsutil**: roles
**fsmo maintenance**: connections
**server connections**: connect to server dc3
Binding to dc3 …
Connected to dc3 using credentials of locally logged on user.
**server connections**: q
**fsmo maintenance**: select operation target
**select operation target**: list roles for connected server
Server "dc3" knows about 5 roles
Schema - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=mgaming,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration
,DC=mgaming,DC=com
Naming Master - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=mgaming,CN=Sites,CN=Config
uration,DC=mgaming,DC=com
PDC - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=mgaming,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC
=mgaming,DC=com
RID - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=mgaming,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC
=mgaming,DC=com
Infrastructure - CN=NTDS Settings,CN=DC3,CN=Servers,CN=mgaming,CN=Sites,CN=Confi
guration,DC=mgaming,DC=com
**select operation target**: q
**fsmo maintenance**: q
**ntdsutil**: q

---

***------NEW results after some work------***

**netdom query fsmo:**

```
Schema master               DC1.domain.com  
Domain naming master        DC1.domain.com  
PDC                         DC1.domain.com  
RID pool manager            DC1.domain.com  
Infrastructure master       DC1.domain.com  
The command completed successfully.
```

**dcdiag**:

```
Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = DC1
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: <domain>\DC1
      Starting test: Connectivity
         ......................... DC1 passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: <domain>\DC1
      Starting test: Advertising
         Warning: DC1 is not advertising as a time server.
         ......................... DC1 failed test Advertising
      Starting test: FrsEvent
         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the
         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause
         Group Policy problems.
         ......................... DC1 passed test FrsEvent
      Starting test: DFSREvent
         ......................... DC1 passed test DFSREvent
      Starting test: SysVolCheck
         ......................... DC1 passed test SysVolCheck
      Starting test: KccEvent
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000829
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:58:54
            Event String:
            This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the f
ollowing number of days.
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000829
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:58:54
            Event String:
            This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the f
ollowing number of days.
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000829
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:58:54
            Event String:
            This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the f
ollowing number of days.
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000829
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:58:54
            Event String:
            This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the f
ollowing number of days.
         A warning event occurred.  EventID: 0x80000829
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:58:54
            Event String:
            This directory partition has not been backed up since at least the f
ollowing number of days.
         ......................... DC1 passed test KccEvent
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         ......................... DC1 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         ......................... DC1 passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         ......................... DC1 passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         ......................... DC1 passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         ......................... DC1 passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: Replications
         [Replications Check,Replications Check] Inbound replication is
         disabled.
         To correct, run "repadmin /options DC1 -DISABLE_INBOUND_REPL"
         [Replications Check,DC1] Outbound replication is disabled.
         To correct, run "repadmin /options DC1 -DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL"
         ......................... DC1 failed test Replications
      Starting test: RidManager
         ......................... DC1 passed test RidManager
      Starting test: Services
            w32time Service is stopped on [DC1]
         ......................... DC1 failed test Services
      Starting test: SystemLog
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0002719
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:10:16
            Event String:
            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer MRInterCA01.<domain>
.com using any of the configured protocols.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0000428
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:10:16
            Event String:
            The terminal server cannot install a new template-based certificate
to be used for Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0\Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) aut
hentication and encryption. The following error occured: The RPC server is unava
ilable.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0002719
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:15:17
            Event String:
            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer MRInterCA01.<domain>
.com using any of the configured protocols.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0000428
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:15:17
            Event String:
            The terminal server cannot install a new template-based certificate
to be used for Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0\Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) aut
hentication and encryption. The following error occured: The RPC server is unava
ilable.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0002719
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:20:21
            Event String:
            DCOM was unable to communicate with the computer MRInterCA01.<domain>
.com using any of the configured protocols.
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0xC0000428
            Time Generated: 01/18/2019   15:20:21
            Event String:
            The terminal server cannot install a new template-based certificate
to be used for Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0\Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) aut
hentication and encryption. The following error occured: The RPC server is unava
ilable.
         ......................... DC1 failed test SystemLog
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         ......................... DC1 passed test VerifyReferences


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test
         CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : <domain>
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... <domain> passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... <domain> passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : <domain>.com
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355
         A Time Server could not be located.
         The server holding the PDC role is down.
         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error
         1355
         A Good Time Server could not be located.
         ......................... <domain>.com failed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... <domain>.com passed test Intersite
```

Comment: You need to provide the output of `netdom query fsmo`on DC1

Comment: I've edited the original post to include this crucial piece of information. Thank you Greg.

Comment: The only functional domain controller doesn't know the FSMO role holders, that's not good. Try ntdsutil as described in method 3: https://www.petri.com/determining_fsmo_role_holders

Comment: Added NTDSUtil output. Thank you so much for your input.

Comment: Is it pointing to itself for DNS, and is DNS running and all of the required records present? You may also want to check the Directory Services and DNS event logs for anything useful.

Comment: DC1 was pointing to DC2, for the primary DNS and to itself (loopback) for the secondary DNS.


Since we last spoke, I've done the following:
(1) Seized all roles to DC1. The "netdom query fsmo" output resulted as expected afterward; showing DC1 owning all roles.
(2) Since DC2 won't boot, I couldn't properly decommission it. I manually/forcefully deleted DC2 from the domain (delete all records in 'Sites & Service' and DNS). Some event log error message went away after this.
(3) At this point, I was able to join a pc to the domain again - whew...
(4) I will later rebuild a second DC.

Comment: There is still some cleanup to do, before the domain is working properly again - I think. I say this based off of the new DCDIAG results. I'll post them in the original post, as they won't all fit in this "comment"

Comment: Glad it is sorted out. Don't forget to run a full backup on the DC. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to reconfigure the time service on DC1. You can use the commands below:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm.exe /config /manualpeerlist:”time.windows.com” /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:YES /update
w32tm.exe /config /update
net stop w32time
net start w32time
```

Then run the following command to view the configuration:

w32tm /query /configuration

```
C:\Users\Administrator>w32tm /query /configuration
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 5 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 6 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 172800 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 7 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 100 (Local)


[TimeProviders]

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Local)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 1 (Local)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Local)
Type: NTP (Local)
NtpServer: time.windows.com (Local)

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

VMICTimeProvider (Local)
DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
```

Make sure that the Type is listed as NTP and that NtpServer is listed as time.windows.com (or whatever time source you choose to use).